# Wait until service shutdown complete before moving to next block in chef recipe

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I'm running chef recipe block to stop particular service running on port 9991. here is my chef recipe block.

```
execute "run script" do
    command "./stop.sh"
    cwd "#{node[MY_ENVIRONMENT]['home']}"
    user "centos"
    action :run
    only_if { ::File.exist?("#{node[MY_ENVIRONMENT]['home']}/stop.sh") }
end
```

According to the my application it might take some time to shutdown the application by breaking the TCP connections which has been established. I cannot tell how long it will take.

What I need is to wait chef-client to run next block until my service get stop completely. I can ensure the service is down by executing below command and if its get `echo $?;`  -ne result from bash.

```
ss -a | grep -E '9991'  # reason for this is my application can have close_wait, fin_wait status within the shutdown process
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be best to put that in the `stop.sh` itself probably. Chef will wait until that script ends, so whatever it does is up to you. Otherwise you can use a `ruby_block` resource, but you'll need a way to get the PID of your program:

```
ruby_block 'wait until down' do
  block do
    begin
      loop do
        Process.kill(0, yourpid)
        sleep(1)
       end
    rescue Errno::ESRCH
      # This space left intentionally blank, when the PID is gone, we're done.
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  you have mentioned that "Chef will wait until that script ends, so whatever it does is up to you"

I have already done this. but seems chef not waiting until shell script finish. do I need to add any option into my chef code?

Comment: No, nor is there even any way to turn it off. It will fully block on the exit of `stop.sh`.